# Yahoo Pipes - two RSS feeds - Compare item contents based on IMDB Link

Tags: rss, compare, yahoo-pipes, imdb

i have two RSS feeds. First one is a news site rss feed with one IMDB Link in every "item.description".
example:

item.title: 
Baymax - Riesiges Robowabohu

item.description:

Release Date...: 07.04.2015

Imdb...........: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084

Second one is my IMBD watchlist.
example:

```
<item>
  <pubDate>Wed, 08 Apr 2015 08:26:05 GMT</pubDate>
    <title>Big Hero 6 (2014)</title>
    <link>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084/</link>;
    <guid>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2245084/</guid>;
    <description></description>
</item>
```

As u can see i can not compare/link the title because one title is in german, the other one the original US title. Now my idea is to compare it based on the IMDB link.

Now i want an output when a new movie appears in the first rss feed (news site) that it compares it with mit IMDB watchlist rss feed based on the IMDB Link.

how can I implement this with yahoo pipes?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with YQL module with the following query:
select * from rss where url='feed1' and guid in (select guid from rss where url='feed2')